Gradle Build Fails with Missing APK After Clearing Cache and Removing .gradle Folder in Flutter
In my project, I have implemented the Stripe tap to pay via method channel. and for that I have updated the dependencies as per the requirement.
In my case, I have change my gradle version from 7.5 to 8.7 as it was compatible with my other dependencies. the flow was working fine but after flutter pub cache clean and removing .gradle folder, I'm facing this error.
I have tried many solution from the stack overflow, as well as Other AI tools to resolve this but the issue is still same!
Error: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under /Users/<UserName>/StudioProjects/<ProjectName>/build, but the tool
couldn't find it.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _exitWithExpectedFileNotFound (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:1131:3)
#2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:582:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:224:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:581:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:532:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:57:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:808:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>


Have you tried to do flutter pub get first after clearing the cache and deleting .gradle? Are you using Android Studio? Can you provide a specific approach you've taken before encountering that exception? In order to reproduce or understand the issue well

Check below things in your project
Have you updated both gradle-wrapper.properties and build.gradle to match Gradle 8.7
Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> check Android SDK Build-Tools (latest version installed).
Update or resolve conflicts in pubspec.yaml
flutter pub outdated

Run these commands
flutter clean
flutter pub get
./gradlew clean
./gradlew --stop
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
flutter build apk --debug


I have tried this solution but may be there is another issue with the configuration. I've updated the gradle dependencies and other related versions. So, that might be conflicts.
I am not sure about this.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71337, This issue looks simmilar to your try following it if you have not tryied yet.

Yes, I had tried it but after the rewiring the project settings, It was sorted out. But the issue wasn't figured out! Thank you Tech Ramakant for your support!
